# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "content" is null

Tags: java

Выпрыгивает ошибка `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "content" is null` всё не как не могу починить

Вот место вызова :

```
final String EXAMPLE_MESSAGE = "example_message";
final String EXAMPLE_MEETING = "example_meeting";
final String USER_EXAMPLE_NAME = "user_";
final RoleEnum role = RoleEnum.INVESTOR;
final int totalUsers = 100;
...

System.out.println(RedisNotificationRepoService.NOTIFY_USER_CHANNEL_PREFIX + USER_EXAMPLE_NAME + i + ":" + role.name());
String capturedMsg = messages.get(USER_EXAMPLE_NAME + i);
RedisNotificationMessage redisCapturedMessage = new ObjectMapper().readValue(capturedMsg, RedisNotificationMessage.class);
                assertEquals (EXAMPLE_MESSAGE, redisCapturedMessage.getText());
```

Вот вызов но так и непонятно почему такая ошибка выпрыгивает когда `capturedMsg`  не пустой
**Что делать ??**

Comment: Тут речь идет о каком-то `content`. Может, имеется более подробный стектрэйс с номером строки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас `capturedMsg` не `null`? Проверьте. [Проверка на `null`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L1450) прямолинейная, там нечему ломаться. И ещё было бы полезно увидеть стек исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Сам поразился ответу, думал вопрос стоит удалить , но так как ребята дали комментарии решил выдать ответ

Ответ нахоился в настройках redis сервера который поднимает программа
заменил в xml файле `p:host-name="d01db01"` на  `p:host-name="localhost"`

```
<!-- Чтобы не конфликтовать с уже установленным редисом, порт переопределяем -->
    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:use-pool="true"
            p:host-name="localhost"
          p:port="36379" />
```

И всё заработало .